# Magento2 Cache Invalidation Questions

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

If FPC is enabled and you perform some admin activities, the one or more cache is likely to be invalidated.

- What's the effect of this cache invalidation in performance?
- Can I safely disable the cache invalidation method? We are refreshing cache daily at mid-night btw.

Comment: For exemple: if FPC is enabled and after an order a product goes out of stock you need cache invalidation to have your product page updated as out of stock. Otherwise it will continue showing your product in stock.

Comment: @JonathanRibas As long as the customer cannot purchase the product, we are happy to live with it. Anyway we refreshing cache every day at midnight.

Comment: Have you got performance issues with cache invalidation to do so every day at midnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the effect of this cache invalidation in performance?

There is no any effect on performances. It's just an indicator which says that something is changed, and cached data doesn't reflect the current state.

> Can I safely disable the cache invalidation method? We are refreshing cache daily at mid-night btw.

You can, but there is no way to do it from Magento2 itself out-of-the-box; you'll have to disable observers in vendor/magento/module-page-cache, and vendor/magento/module-cache-invalidate for varnish.